# I could not figure out why my code is not working - codeforce - Brain's Photos

Tags: c++

This is my code programmed to print `#Color` if the user entered any of `C`, `Y`, `M` characters. But if the user entered `W` ,`B`, `G` then the program is suppose to print out `#Black&White`. Unfortunately, my code skips my first for loop and goes straight to printing out `#Black&White`, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<char>colors;
  int row, column, letters = 0;
  cin>>row, column;
  letters = row * column;

  for(int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
  {
    char temp;
    cin>>temp;
    colors.push_back(temp);
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < letters; j++)
   {
     if(colors[j] == 'C' || colors[j] == 'Y' || colors[j] == 'M')
     {
       cout<<"#color"<<endl;
       return 0;
     }
   }

  cout<<"#Black&White"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what value does `letters = row * column;` result in?

Comment: it is just to know that how many letters are present(number of letters the vector is going to hold). The user is suppose to input their values like a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You have two expressions in the line `cin>>row, column;` The comma separates them, and `column` is a useless expression in this case.

You probably mean `cin >> row >> column;`

`column` is being used uninitialized. If it happens to take the value `0`, the body of your first loop never executes. Beware, using uninitialized variables in this way can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Yup, i do not know why i could not see that. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Are you compiling with g++ by chance? Use the `-Wall` switch to enable all warnings. In g++ 5.x and undoubtedly earlier versions, this throws warnings about the right operand of the comma operator having no effect as well as `column` potentially being uninitialized.

Comment: Yes I am using g++ on cygwin. I compiled this code with -Wall enabled and it got the problem. so cooooool